# Update android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite, upgrade, apk

I developed an Android application. I installed the apk on my tablet.

Now, I want just modify few code lines and one table of my SQLite database, but I don't want reinstall my apk, I want make an upgrade.

How can I build this upgrade mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android doesn't provide a "patch" mechanism. You need to create a new APK and install it over the existing application.

Comment: Can I preserve the data in my database?

Comment: Yes. If the user installs the new APK while the old application is installed, Android will update the application (which will preserve any data in your private data areas, including database). However, if you are changing the schema or content of your database, you may need to "upgrade" your database as well. See `SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade()` at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: ok. And Can I call the installation of new apk from the old running apk?

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically/4969421#4969421

Comment: you are always precious! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can preserve the data in your database. There is a method [onUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) in SQLiteOpenHelper which you can override to modify your table(s).